# Inserting values to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have successfully check if NamesFromA from TableA exist in NamesFromB TableB using this code.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON(NameFromA = NameFromB)
```

And I also able to output the names that exist. Now I want to store the Names that exist in both table into another table named "existed" and column "NAME". What should I do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `insert into ... select` statement.

```
insert into existed (existed.name) SELECT a.name FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB ON(NameFromA = NameFromB)
```

See the [official mysql documentatio](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)n for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO existed (`name`)
(SELECT NameFromA FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON(NameFromA = NameFromB))
```

Comment: i got a "Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous" error.